# Set Tile SIze by X and Y

Tags: tilesize

I'm watching some videos which explain how to make rending (especially if Cycles) much faster.
Apparently the size of the titel plays a huge role for rendering.

In all videos, they show how they actually can change the size of the tiles by their X and Y. Unfortunally, I can only set one specific number (the standard value is 2048 if I'm not wrong).

Is there a way to enable this option?

Comment: As far as i know, Tile size X and Y was available on Blender 2.93

Comment: I'm afraid they remove the option :/
And apparently the "auto tile size" add-on is automatically installed, but i'm not sure if it gives me the best performance for rendering